# Web Shell File Identification

Tags: python

I would like to know how to distinguish whether a web file is included in a web shell or not in a PL file, jpg file, png file, etc.
For example, I want to distinguish files that are executable like exe, vir, but are not actually executed.

I'm sorry for using the translator because my English is not good enough.